# Pass a parentcomponent variable trough the router-outlet "child" component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I've a product "parent" page which has 3 routerlinks that will change a part of the page to e.g. a "child" overview page, a gallery page or a specs page.

Now the information about the product is held by the parent product page ( the details, links to images and specs ) in a variable "product". How do I access the "product" variable of the parent component from the child components, which are used by my routeroutlet?

Comment: Have you tried with @input?

Comment: use 'services' , 'events' etc

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I'm not using the component selector, but the router-outlet tag, which has no support of any input vars

Comment: @anshuVersatile elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  private mainSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  main$ = this.mainSource.asObservable();

  setWorking(isWorking: boolean) {
    this.mainSource.next(isWorking);
  }
}
```

Component

```
private subscription: Subscription

constructor(private appService: AppService){ }

ngOnInit(){

  this.appService.setWorking(false);

  this.subscription = this.appService.main$.subscribe(isWorking => {
    if (isWorking) { alert("Tio"); }
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```